# Ansible - reading inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file

```
[hosttype1]
Server
Server2
[hosttype2]
server3
server4
```

I am trying to read this as a whole into ansible.  The file is used in the normal way to define hosts and types for code deploy, but I need to also read the full content for adding into a config file.

the inventory file differs for different environments being deployed, so there is no fixed location for it.

Is it possible to read the file and create a variable that I can then loop over and use the hosttype and a comparitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use it as an inventory. For example

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[hosttype1]
Server
Server2
[hosttype2]
server3
server
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_groups: "{{ groups|difference(['all', 'ungrouped']) }}"
    my_hosts: "{{ my_groups|map('extract', groups)|list }}"
    my_inventory: "{{ dict(my_groups|zip(my_hosts)) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_inventory
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_inventory:
    hosttype1:
    - Server
    - Server2
    hosttype2:
    - server3
    - server
```

Comment: thanks for this but the my_hosts variable is ending up as <generator object do_map at 0x7f3d30658dc0"  Which i guess is a fault within ansible.  I will start my google ritual to find out what it might be.

Comment: I see. Add explicit ``list``. I updated the code.

Comment: The above code looks like it could be generic.  How does the code know I what the data from the inventory?  Is groups a hard coded reference to the inventory file?

The reason I ask is that I need to create a different file with the same structure so would like to understand how that might be possible.

Comment: ``How does the code know I want the data from the inventory? ``  See [the command line using the -i <path> option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-to-build-your-inventory).  ``Is groups a hard coded reference to the inventory file?`` See [groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables).